# Panda operation on large dataset using jupiter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large csv file (10Go) A small example:

```
          timestamp       LAT        LON
0  2018-10-18T00:00:00  36.97696  -89.10680
1  2018-10-18T00:00:00  46.08972 -122.92928
2  2018-10-18T00:00:00  48.10739 -122.77227
3  2018-10-18T00:00:00  28.72571  -89.52151
4  2018-10-18T00:00:00  61.11447 -146.35110
```

I wanna create a new category variable  time slots for each 30 min that works but only for small data:

```py
#I first convert timestamp which is a string to datetime then I do this to get MM:SS time slots
df['time_slot'] = ((df['date']-pd.TimedeltaIndex.dt.minute%30,m)) - ((df['date']-pd.TimedeltaIndex.dt.second,s))).dt.strftime("%H:%M")
```

When loading large data Jupiter kernel just shuts down when trying to craete those time slots (knowing thats its working fine with a small dataset).

Comment: do you use the data for something after creating the time slots?

Comment: Yes I use it to create a geopandas dataframe to plot in a map and also create other variables like distance

Answer (score 1):

If you think it is a resource issue you should slice the data up and process the transformation in small batches. I would try a generator.